# help with linq to sql many to many query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have following entities

```
A_Entity
-----------
AId

AB_Entity
-----------
AId
BId

B_Entity
-----------
BId
```

I have a function that helps in building the query based on the input provided. In this case I have to build a query to fetch all A_Entities that have matching BId (provided as input to the function)

```
public static IQueryable<A_Entity> BuildQuery(IQueryable<A_Entity> query, int BId)
{
   // Something like query.where(a => a.select_all_a_that_have corresponding_b_with_Id_equalto_BId)
}
```

I know there has to be join between AB_Entity and A_Entity but dont know how to apply it to build IQueryable and return back.

Thanks

Comment: Are there navigation properties on A_Entity? That is, does A_Entity have a property AB_Entities? If not, you will need to pass in a means to construct a queryable of AB_Entity and B_Entity on which to create the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query = query.Where(a => a.AB_Entities.Any(ab => ab.BId == BId));
return query;
```

Comment: This will not work since AB_Entities is a EntitySet<AB_Entity>